# Честить - хорошо это или плохо?

Tags: значение-слов

Насколько я понимаю, "честить" - это воздавать кому-то честь, хвалить, славить, ведь это слово и происходит от слова "честь". Читаем у Алексея Толстого:

*Цари Константин и Василий

По целой империи пишут приказ

Владимир де нас от погибели спас,

Его чтоб все люди честил*.

Но сейчас его почему-то чаще можно услышать в контексте негативном: "Его честили перед всем классом" - то есть, ругали, обсуждали, высмеивали.
Почему у этого слова два настолько противоположных значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывать честь – это второе значение слова, причём устаревшее. По крайней мере, в толковом словаре помечено *устар*. А первое значение – сильно бранить, ругать. Думаю, развилось из того, прежнего значения. Сравните: мы сейчас часто иронически называем "умником" как раз неумного человека.

Answer (score 1):

Слово «честить» могло приобрести подобный негативный смысл в современном языке благодаря созвучию со словом «чистить». Ведь, по сути, процесс «чещения» сводится к попытке **очищения** человека от мыслей поступать в дальнейшем ненадлежащим образом.